# When does each boss theme play?

Tags: terraria, terraria-mobile

I was just wondering: In Terraria, when does each boss theme play? I know the 1st theme plays during the EoC.

Comment: It doesn't plays *after*, it plays *while* the boss/invasion is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find [a list of all the tracks](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Music) on the wiki. I'll list the boss themes below with quotes from the wiki on when they play.

## Boss 1

> It plays during invasions by the Goblin Army and during the fight with the Eye of Cthulhu, King Slime, Eater of Worlds, Skeletron, Lepus (Mobile), and Turkor the Ungrateful (Mobile). In hardmode, it also plays during the fight with Skeletron Prime and Duke Fishron.

## Boss 2

> It plays during the fight with the Wall of Flesh and The Twins, which suits them very well.

## Boss 3

> It plays during the fight with The Destroyer, as well as invasions by the Frost Legion. As of 1.2, this track is also played during the fight with the Brain of Cthulhu.

## Golem

> It plays during the fight with the Golem and Pirate Invasion.

## Plantera

> It plays during the fight with Plantera.

## Boss 4

> It plays during the fight against the Queen Bee.
>       This track was added in the 1.2 patch, along with all the possible situations it plays in. This theme was originally exclusive to the console edition, where it is used differently. In the console version, it is used in the fight of the Eye of Cthulhu, and Ocram.

Comment: Pretty sure Eye of Cthulhu isn't PC exclusive. Also, I read that the Boss 4 theme also plays for Ocram... I was just checking, since he wasn't on here.

Comment: I did not include mobile only content since this is tagged as `terraria` and not `terraria-mobile`. I can put that in the answer if you like though.

Comment: Sorry, I put that tag in there. Also, fix the EoC thing.

Comment: That is a quote directly from the Wiki. In the mobile version, `Boss 4` plays.

Comment: I mean for the Eye of Cthulhu fight. The Eye of Cthulhu is NOT PC Exclusive... I've played on Mobile and fought it many many times

Comment: Yes. That quote is saying that that boss music only plays for the Eye of Cthulhu on PC.

Comment: I have updated the answer to include information about the songs played for mobile.

Comment: I've heard the theme play, and I play almost exclusively on Mobile and Console.

Comment: Then I would encourage you to edit the Wiki entry: http://terraria.gamepedia.com/index.php?title=Music&action=edit&section=8